# How can I prevent two onscroll event listeners that call each other from making the resulting action jerky?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a faux scrollbar I've created with JS, and a table I want it to scroll.  There's two possible scenarios:

1. I want the scrollbar to move when I scroll the table (using a finger on mobile or two-touch on touchpad)
2. I want the table to move when I use the scrollbar

This is what I have so far.

```
tableContainerDiv.addEventListener('scroll', function(e)  {
    document.getElementById('faux-scrollbar').scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
});

fauxScrollbar.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('table-container-div').scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
});
```

It works perfectly, but is predictably a bit janky, as they fire each other off repeatedly.  If I comment out either listener, the effect works smoothly, albeit only one way, not both ways.

I'm not sure how to fix this, but I assume it can be fixed...?

I've tried setting a variable in each event listener, that gets set on the first fire to identify the originator, and checked in each listener, but tied myself in knots...  I also tried `e.originalEvent`, before discovering that was jQuery only, and it seems the vanilla option is `isTrusted` always says true, for some reason.

Thank you

Comment: Probably try event delegation instead. Something like: `document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { if(e.target && e.target.id == 'faux-scrollbar'){ document.getElementById(e.target.id).scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft; } else if(e.target && e.target.id == 'table-container-div'){ document.getElementById(e.target.id).scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft; } });`. This has the benefit that only one of them fires at a time (I think). Not entirely sure, hence the comment and not an answer.

Comment: It's 2021... I think trying to reimplement one's own scrolling system is a bad idea because browsers have heavily optimized their own native-scrolling code-paths (and got the UX figured out, e.g. Apple's elastic-band scrolling). There's also a _lot_ of edge-cases to consider (e.g. touch-drag vs mouse drag vs. 3-line scroll wheel, vs. high-res scroll-wheel, etc). At least tell us that your content is still scrollable when JavaScript is disabled...

Comment: I just tried that @icecub, and it didn't fire at all.  I think because I'm scrolling an element, not the document.  It fires when I'm scrolling up and down the page, but not when scrolling left and right in my table, as, by design, the page stays fixed.

Comment: It is still scrollable when JS is disabled @dai, via the standard scrollbar at the bottom of the table.  Since my table is long, I wish to have a scrollbar at the top, with position:sticky so it's visible as the user scrolls down the page/table.

Comment: I'm just trying to sync the scroll of two elements, both of which have the same content width and box width.  I think it should be possible, and it shouldn't be janky, but maybe I'm wrong!

Comment: The event delegation attaches to any scroll event in your entire website (the document / DOM). So any element that fires the scroll event, will get processed by it. That's why you have the if statement to check if it's being fired by one of the elements you actually wish to listen for (and do nothing in case it isn't). The only problem in that code might be the use `this` in there, as it probably refers to `document` and not the element. So you'll probably need to fix that and directly target the element instead.

Comment: I don't know - I had a console.log as the first line in the event handler and it never ran, as far as I could tell!  I've used the accepted answer now, thank you for your contribution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a different approach, instead of listening to two scroll events that fire each other continuously, you may run a single function that checks the current position of both containers and when one of them is different copy the value to the other.

This way you'll never fire a loop:

```js
const tableContainerDiv = document.getElementById('table-container-div');
const fauxScrollbar = document.getElementById('faux-scrollbar');

function copyScroll() {
  if (
    fauxScrollbar.scrollLeft === fauxScrollbar.oldScrollLeft
    &&
    tableContainerDiv.scrollLeft !== tableContainerDiv.oldScrollLeft
  ) {
    /// only tableContainerDiv changed value
    fauxScrollbar.scrollLeft = tableContainerDiv.scrollLeft;
  } else if (
    fauxScrollbar.scrollLeft !== fauxScrollbar.oldScrollLeft
    &&
    tableContainerDiv.scrollLeft === tableContainerDiv.oldScrollLeft
  ) {
    /// only fauxScrollbar changed value
    tableContainerDiv.scrollLeft = fauxScrollbar.scrollLeft;
  }
  
  /// save values for next recursion
  fauxScrollbar.oldScrollLeft = fauxScrollbar.scrollLeft;
  tableContainerDiv.oldScrollLeft = tableContainerDiv.scrollLeft;
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(copyScroll);
  
  
}

copyScroll();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.container:before {
  content: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  display: block;
  width: 2000px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container" id="faux-scrollbar"></div>
  <div class="container" id="table-container-div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I wanted to do something like this but didn't think it was possible, it looks like window.requestAnimationFrame is the key thing that I didn't know this morning, when I started down this path.  I'll try it now, thank you.

Comment: Once we would have used setInterval or setTimeout, but requestAnimationFrame is more performant, in fact it is mostly used to play animations and games.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that works well.  One detail I left out was that actually I sometimes have 20 such tables and faux scrollbars on the same page.  With this function defined in a loop that processes those 20 tables, it ends up firing 20 times for each animationFrame... which seems ok in my quick test, but does shout "DANGER" a bit...